# crash new android process stops entire application

Tags: android, process

I have a android application, which has mainctivty and it starts other activity "secondactivity", this secondactivity I am starting in a new process by adding android:process=":SecondProcess" in manifestfile.

I am starting second activity using below code.

```
Intent ssIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(ssIntent);
```

below is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test">

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.SecondActivity"
        android:process=":SecondProcess"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_basic"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
```

There is crash(I added for testing) in the Secondactivity, now as per my understanding only secondprocess Should gets killed whenever crash happens in secondactivity as its running in separate process , but in my test entire android application gets stopped .

Could you please let me know is there a way to handle such a way that only second process should killed and it should not disturb the complete application.

I can handle with try catch, but my goal is to make sure first Activity will be still alive even after second one crashes..

Comment: can you post the manifest file?

Comment: re-edited post with maifiest, please check

Comment: also can you post the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: I only introduced the crash in second activity, my goal is to not catch the crash, its to make first activity alive even after second activity crash.

Answer (score -1):

User `try/catch` to handle the error in `SecondActivity`...so that it won't crash the whole app.

```
try {
  //Code that creates error in SecondActivity 
}catch(Exception e) { 
  //Close the activity after exception
  finish();
}
```

Comment: yes, I can add with try catch, but my goal is to make sure first Activity will be still alive even after second one crashes

Comment: using try/catch properly will prevent the crash...try it as i showed in reply.

Comment: I only introduced the crash in second activity, my goal is to not catch the crash, its to make first activity alive even after second activity crash

Comment: This is an unhelpful answer because you may not always be able to add a try/catch. E.g. you are using 3rd party code which does stuff in its own thread, or you are using native code which does not produce Java exceptions.